# Laravel Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure

Tags: laravel, routes, closures

When I commenting all routes I getting this error. 
Please say me, what are the closure routes? And why showing this error

Comment: Are you executing the command `routes:cache`?

Comment: Yes. After it i getting the error

Comment: its intended behaviour. You can't cache routes if you have closure in them.

Comment: I am not understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closure is an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) which is used to [define routes without an action](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#basic-routing):

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return 'hello world';
});
```

The example above returns `hello world` when you call the route `/test` in your browser.

You can't cache routes that are referencing a closure.

There are two routes using closures in a default Laravel app: in the files [`routes/api.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/routes/api.php#L17) and [`routes/web.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/routes/web.php#L16). Remove them or move them to a controller and you are able to cache your routes.

Here's [an issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22034) in the Laravel framework repository which is discussing this behaviour.

Comment: is it an bug? can I leave unchanged?

Comment: Not, it's intended behaviour. In a production app you don't want to have any closure routes.